# How to hide a sliding checkbox's labels when switching on/off?

Tags: css

I have built a sliding on/off switch. There is one thing that is not working. How can I hide the switch's not active label?

Here is a JS fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/26gv0uey/.

CSS

```
.onoffswitch {
  position: relative;
  width: 65px;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
}

.onoffswitch-checkbox {
  display: none;
}

.onoffswitch-label {
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid #ced2d4;
  height: 30px;
}

.onoffswitch-on,
.onoffswitch-off {
  height: 30px;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 26px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #43b02a;
  font-weight: 700;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s;
          transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s;
}

.onoffswitch-on {
  left: 100%;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.onoffswitch-off {
  right: 0;
  padding-right: 25px;
}

.onoffswitch-switch {
  display: block;
  width: 20px;
  background: #5e6b71;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  height: 30px;
  right: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s;
          transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s;
}

.onoffswitch-checkbox:checked + .onoffswitch-label .onoffswitch-on {
  left: 0;
  padding-left: 30px;
}

.onoffswitch-checkbox:checked + .onoffswitch-label .onoffswitch-off {
  right: 100%;
  padding-right: 5px;
}

.onoffswitch-checkbox:checked + .onoffswitch-label .onoffswitch-switch {
  right: 45px;
}
```

HTML

```
  <div class="onoffswitch">
      <input class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="isActive" name="isActive" type="checkbox">
                  <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="isActive">
                  <span class="onoffswitch-off">OFF</span>
                  <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
                  <span class="onoffswitch-on">ON</span>
       </label>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add `overflow: hidden;` to your `onoffswitch` class, it will hide everything outside the `onoffswitch` `div`:

```
.onoffswitch {
    position: relative;
    width: 65px;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/26gv0uey/1/)

Answer (score 0):

If what I understood is correct, here is the [example](https://jsfiddle.net/26gv0uey/2/).

Add:

```
.onoffswitch-label{
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try It:

```
.onoffswitch {
    position: relative;
    width: 65px;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```